# Frustating Error in python 3; TypeError: str, bytes or bytearray expected, not int

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, tkinter

I am trying to make an application with python that allows users to connect to a server and chat with each other. The users have to enter a Host(IP) and port, then press a button to connect to a server. The buttons and boxes are done with tkinter. When I use a tkinter button to connect to a server It returns:

```
TypeError: str, bytes or bytearray expected, not int
```

Trying to connect with something like this works:

```
HOST = input("Enter Host: ")
```

The relevant code is as follows:

```
#To connect to a server host
def connect():

    HOST = etyHost.get()
    PORT = etyPort.get()

    if isinstance(HOST, str) == True:
        print ("Yes")
    else:
        print ("NO")
    print(HOST, PORT)
    if not PORT:
        PORT = 33000  # Default value.
    else:
        PORT = int(PORT)

    client_socket.connect(ADDR)

#Entry box
etyHost = Entry(jahchat)
etyHost.pack()
etyHost.place(x = 0, y = 250)

#Entry box
etyPort = Entry(jahchat)
etyPort.pack()
etyPort.place(x = 0, y = 275)

#Button
btnConnect = Button(jahchat, text = "Connect", command = connect)
btnConnect.config(width = 20)
btnConnect.place(x = 0, y = 320)

HOST = 1
PORT = 1

client_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
BUFSIZ = 1024
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)
```

I have tried using str() to convert the port and Ip integers to strings. Python recognizes it as a string but the issue is not resolved.
All answers are appreciated.

Comment: Can you include full stacktrace?

Comment: You use `client_socket.connect(ADDR)` - and `ADDR` is always `(1,1)`. It's not an object with host and port fields, it doesn't change when the PORT and HOST change

Comment: Have you tried removing the HOST=1, PORT=1 command? I doubt the HOST shall be something different to a number.

Comment: I first of all recommend that you print out and see the values that you are passing to the server. In addition to that, have you tried like this `b'192.168.0.0'`

Comment: You need to update `ADDR` before the line `client_socket.connect(ADDR)` inside `connect()`. Or simply use `client_socket.connect((HOST, PORT))` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You must first convert the string that contains the IP address into a byte or a string of bytes and then start communicating.
According to the code below, your error will be resolved.
Make sure your code is working correctly overall.

```
string = '192.168.1.102'
new_string = bytearray(string,"ascii")
ip_receiver = new_string
s.sendto(text.encode(), (ip_receiver, 5252))
```